# How are modern ACDC power supplies desgined?

Tags: power-supply, inductance, ac-dc

I wonder about how exactly modern, but mundane ACDC power supplies (your phone power supply) are designed. Maybe my misunderstanding comes from one of the following assumptions:

1. Modern AC-DCs galvanically isolate their internals from the grid
2. If no device is connected to the dc side, the physics behind a transformer are (almost) the same as that of a coil in an AC, thus the current is indirectly proportional to the inductance of the coil
3. If the inductance of the coil is lower, less power can be transferred using the B - Field.
4. Modern Power supplies do not consume energy, when no device is connected.

But I do not get this together. Definitely, the inductance must be high, otherwise you would toast the grid and consume energy because your internal resistance is never 0. See [here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAmaBmA7MgHMh2wBOZZSBMBANhEMJCQUnoFMBaMMAKADdwAWPuAzUwAlFijgQlJsjRMFUaAk4AbFNmz9BOLcglNs0DJDBoQrGGFJ9amyNmGE%20aYlE4B3beOQa9Bz29RQWChakhOPkhzNDQRNz5KHSpJMAB9JLTINKjCDDSENLBoSjT2IsDQqrdQiK9dbzwRMQio5OaQmpalSEozKSYAMwBDVQBnZk4Ae0kk1JJCWXkeuAgmLhmIOYwQXJ2kGF8ICCjpkB25pj36JV8785A0TjQtCAAxNZ7jpnYQAEkAHYAEwArgBjAAuwwBYMmQA).

But if you use a high inductance, I am not sure you could still transfer that amounts of power, power supplies can transfer.

If I measure the resistance of modern power supplies I get this insane value. (EDIT: probably some isolation?)

[image: If I measure the resistance of modern power supplies I get this]

Comment: The device you're measuring is a switch mode power supply.  These first convert to DC and then switch that through a transformer.  Since you're measuring the supply unpowered, the switch is off and you get very high resistance between the lines.

Comment: I assumed something like that, but what happens if I indeed connect it to the ac grid?

Comment: the transformer doesn't run at 50/60Hz, it run in many KHz range.

Comment: @Niclas A very simplified way to look at it is that there is a (semiconductor) switch that connects the primary of the transformer (or coupled inductor) to the input for only as long as necessary to transfer the required amount of power to the secondary.  (And it does it at relatively high frequency) There are a lot of details and differing topologies based on power requirements, but that's a very simplistic way to look at it.

Comment: @dandavis And this would change the impedance of a even a low inductance due to $$I = Lw$$ ?

Comment: @Niclas You're not changing the impedance, you're just connecting the impedance to the rectified AC line for short periods of time.  Suppose your rectified line voltage is 170 V, and your primary inductance is 500 uH.  If you connect the inductance to the input voltage for 5 us,  the current in the inductance would ramp up to 1.7 A.  Then the switch would shut off for some period of time determined by the control loop.

Answer (score 4):

> Maybe my misunderstanding comes from one of the following assumptions...

I think the mistake you may be making is this.

Ignoring any EMI filters that may be present, the component in a typical USB phone "charger" that connects to the mains power is not a transformer, but a rectifier.

The rectified high voltage is then passed through a DC-DC converter giving a low voltage output. The DC-DC converter has a "transformer" in it, although it possibly does not operate with "transformer action" but rather with inductive fly-back action. In either case, this "transformer" provides the galvanic isolation between the mains and the low voltage output.

The DC-DC converter switches the high voltage at a high frequency. As a result, the impedance presented by the "transformer" inside the DC-DC converter is much higher than would be expected if one used the mains frequency for impedance calculation.

Because the DC-DC converter employs switching, there is an inevitable usage of power, by the converter, even when there is no power drawn from the output. This is the quiescent power of the module. However, because the switching is usually achieved with MOSFETs, (fairly low power ones at that), the power consumed in this switching is fairly low, and most phone "chargers" of any quality will not get particularly warm without a load, even if they are plugged in 24/7.

When the internal switches in the DC-DC converter are off, because no mains power is applied to the module, the apparent resistance of the module will seem very high.

Answer (score 3):

> Modern AC-DCs galvanically isolate their internals from the grid

No, they galvanically isolate their *outputs* from the grid. However much of the power supply circuitry is on the "mains" side of the isolation barrier.

> Modern Power supplies do not consume energy, when no device is connected.

They do, but a lot less than the old ones that used a line-frequency transformer did.

> How are modern ACDC power supplies desgined?

A modern power supply generally consists of multiple stages. Starting from the input we generally have.

1. Bridge rectifier, turns AC into DC. Some supplies without power factor correction have a switch which turns the rectifier into a voltage doubler for use in countries with low mains voltages.
2. [Active power factor correction](https://www.nuvation.com/resources/article/power-supply-design-basics-active-power-factor-correction) (optional). This usually consists of a special boost converter, whose operation is modulated to make current proportional to voltage.
3. Primary capacitors. These store energy to carry the power supply through the dips in the mains cycle. If the supply does not have active power factor correction then the voltage on the primary capacitors is determined by the peak voltage of the mains supply. If the supply does have active power factor correction then this voltage is usually a fixed voltage of 380V or so.
4. Isolating switch-mode converter. This provides voltage conversion, voltage regulation and isolation. A transformer is involved as part of the converter, but it operates at a much higher frequency than the mains frequency and it often serves as the inductive element of the switch-mode converter. There are a couple of different variants, two well-known ones are the [flyback converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter) and the
   [forward converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_converter)

> If I measure the resistance of modern power supplies I get this insane value.

The switching circuitry in a switch-mode power supply is deliberately designed not to turn on until the input voltage reaches an acceptable level.

So for low input voltages, the power supply will draw very little current in steady state. As the voltage increases, you will hit a threshold where the switching circuitry turns on. At that point you will see a spike of current draw.

Answer (score 0):

Understand ideal transformers have infinite inductance and can still transfer infinite energy.  Real life ones have inductance that is still quite high and causes minimal no-load losses.

Magnetizing inductance doesn’t prevent energy transfer because secondary currents cancel primary inductance allowing proportional primary currents to flow (conveniently enforcing the laws of physics by ensuring power out is less than power in).

On top of that modern converters also skip cycles when load is low.